# sqlalchemy in_ clause error

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following code that takes a list of years (ints) and creates a sql query to look for fiscalyears in the database that match those in the list:

```
entries = db.session.query(Post).filter((Post.fiscalyear).in_(years))
```

However when I run my code I get the error which directs to the line of the query:

```
DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer: "["
LINE 3: WHERE posts.fy IN ('[', '2', '0', '1', '5', ',', ' ', '...
```

I'm not sure why the query is breaking up the year list in that way. When I print it out, it prints as [2015, 2014].

---

More info on structure: 
the list 'year' is created in one function as [2015, 2014]. Then I call

`return redirect(url_for('.yearresults', years=years))`

This goes to

```
@main.route('/searchresults/<years>')
def yearresults(years):
    entries = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.fiscalyear.in_(years)).all()
    return render_template('yearsearch.html', entries=entries)
```

Comment: Are you sure years is a list of the years? It seems like years is a string looks like: `"[2015, ..."`. Can you please print the value of years before the query line and put it here?

Comment: I printed out years and here is the output! `127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2015 22:28:11] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2015, 2014]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that years is a string so you need to convert this string to list:

```
@main.route('/searchresults/<years>')
    def yearresults(years):
    # convert years to list
    years = years.replace('[', '')
    years = years.replace(']', '')
    years = years.split(',')

    entries = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.fiscalyear.in_(years)).all()
return render_template('yearsearch.html', entries=entries)
```